# How do I test the Elements value in React Native unit testing using Enzyme (Jest)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following Flash.js component to Test

```
export default class SnapshotChild extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>First Text</Text>
            <Text>Second Text</Text>
        </View>
    );
}}
```

And My test cases is

```
describe('Flash Card', () => {
      const flash = shallow(<Flash />);

      it('test the `<Text/>` value',()=>{
       console.log(flash.debug());
       expect(flash.find('Component Text').at(0).text()).toEqual('First Text');
      })});
```

Now when I run this code using **npm test** the result is showing

```
Expected value to equal:
  "First Text"
Received:
  "<Text />"
```

My expected result is **"First Text"** and getting "**Text tag**".
What's the wrong, please please somebody help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use `shallow()` nested `<Text />` are not rendered. So method `.text()` does not know how text will look like. So it seems just returning element name even without all its props.

Sure you can replace `shallow()` with `mount()` but I suggest you [using amazing `.toMatchSnapshot()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing) here.

Then your tests would look like

```
  const flash = shallow(<Flash />);

  it('has valid default output',()=>{
   expect(flash).toMatchSnapshot();
  })});
```

and that would check for both `<Text />` elements and text inside as well.

[UPD] additionaly on why `.text()` works this way. Image you had the same code with slightly different(but equal!) syntax:

```
<Text children={'First Text'} />
```

How could enzyme's helper `.text()` know what to return here without rendering node?

[UPD2] if there is no way to use `toMatchSnapshot()` it's still possible to test `props` directly:

```
expect(flash.find(Text).at(0).props().children).toEqual('First Text')
```

But `toMatchSnapshot` is much better in several ways(readability, maintainability, flexbility and other *abilities)

Comment: Hi @skyboyer, thank you so much for your quick response. Actually I have a task to test with elements value. How can I do this without using toMatchSnapshot()

Comment: the same as with any other prop: `expect(flash.find(Text).at(0).props().children).toEqual('First Text')`

Answer (score 0):

After installing all dependencies,add setup.js

```
    import { configure } from 'enzyme'import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```

In app.test.js :

```
import {shallow} from 'enzyme'import App from '../App';
import React from 'react'describe('test login module',()=>{
    const appWrapper = shallow(<App/>);
    it('renders app module correctly',()=>{
        expect(appWrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

Here is a  [Link](https://reactcodes.blogspot.com/2019/05/tdd-with-react-native-using-jest-and.html)

you may refer